# Extensionally equal predicates and equality of universally quantified applications

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

I am trying to define a recursive predicate using well-founded fixpoints with the obligation to show [F_ext](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Wf.html#Well_founded.FixPoint.F_ext) when rewriting with [Fix_eq](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Wf.html#Fix_eq). The [CPDT](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/GeneralRec.html) says that *most such obligations are dischargeable with straightforward proof automation*, but unhappily this does not appear to be so for my predicate.

I have reduced the problem to the following lemma (from `Proper (pointwise_relation A eq ==> eq) (@all A)`). Is it provable in Coq without [additional axioms](https://github.com/coq/coq/wiki/The-Logic-of-Coq#axioms)?

```
Lemma ext_fa:
  forall (A : Type) (f g : A -> Prop),
    (forall x, f x = g x) ->
    (forall x, f x) = (forall x, g x).
```

It can be shown with extensionality of predicates or functions, but since the conclusion is weaker than the usual one (`f = g`) I naively thought it would be possible to produce a proof without using additional axioms. After all, both sides of the equality only involve applications of `f` and `g`; how could any intensional differences be discerned?

Have I missed a simple proof or is the lemma unprovable?

Comment: I doubt this lemma can be proved without extra axioms, but I cannot give you an authoritative argument.

Comment: Would it be feasible to change the conclusion to `(forall x, f x) <-> (forall x, g x)`? Then the goal is in fact provable.

Comment: You're right. I was thinking about cooking up a version of `Fix_F` (actually `Fix_F_2`) for recursive predicates, but I wanted to double check that I hadn't missed something obvious, and I'm also always trying to better understand the fine details of Coq and it's logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in [this code I wrote a while ago](https://github.com/mit-plv/fiat/blob/38b793d57879d5b4adb132548e4da45348244aee/src/Common/Wf1.v#L312), which includes variants of `Fix_eq` for various numbers of arguments, and don't depend on function extensionality.  Note that you don't need to change `Fix_F`, and can instead just prove variants of `Fix_eq`.

---

To answer the question you asked, rather than solve your context, the lemma you state is called "forall extensionality".

It is present in [Coq.Logic.FunctionalExtensionality](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.FunctionalExtensionality.html), where the axiom of function extensionality is used to prove it.  The fact that the standard library version uses an axiom to prove this lemma is, at the very least, strong evidence that it is not provable without axioms in Coq.

Here is a proof sketch of that fact.  Since Coq is strongly normalizing*, every proof of `x = y` in the empty context is judgmentally equal to `eq_refl`.  That is, if you can prove `x = y` in the empty context, then `x` and `y` are convertible.  Let `f x := inhabited (Vector.t (x + 1))` and let `g x := inhabited (Vector.t (1 + x))`.  It is straightforward to prove `forall x, f x = g x` by induction on `x`.  Therefore, if your lemma were true without axioms, we could get a proof of

```
(forall x, inhabited (Vector.t (x + 1))) = (forall x, inhabited (Vector.t (1 + x)))
```

in the empty context, and hence `eq_refl` ought to prove this statement.  We can easily check and see that `eq_refl` does not prove this statement.  So your lemma `ext_fa` is not provable without axioms.

Note that equality for functions and equality for types are severely under-specified in Coq.  Essentially, the only types (or functions) that you can prove equal in Coq are the ones that are judgmentally equal (or, more precisely, the ones that are expressible as two judgmentally equal lambdas applied to provably-equal closed terms).  The only types that you can *prove* not equal are the ones which are provably not isomorphic.  The only functions that you can *prove* not equal are the ones which provably differ on some concrete element of the domain that you provide.  There's a lot of space between the equalities that you can prove, and the inequalities you can prove, and you don't get to say anything about things in this space without axioms.

*Coq isn't actually strongly normalizing because there are some issues with coinductives.  But modulo that, it's strongly normalizing.

Comment: Thank you for the link and detailed answer. Somehow I missed the `forall_extensionality` lemma in the standard library. I like your idea of trying to show equality by `eq_refl` for a single concrete instance, but I wonder whether the reasoning isn't a bit slippery since the context can't both be empty and contain the natural numbers and their induction principle. But maybe the fact that no induction is possible for the arbitrary `A` type in the original lemma is probably telling.

Comment: I originally thought that Coq's equality was so fine because it was possible to distinguish extensionally equal functions on intensional features, but from what I now understand and what you state above, it seems that this is not possible and that the fineness rather just comes from the typing rules and the form of `eq`. I wonder how equality works in constructive mathematics (i.e., aside from the technicalities of type theory). In any case, I'm going to see if I can adapt your code  and @nesreka's suggestion for my original problem.

Comment: @tbrk Generally, inductive types and their inductions rules are considered primitives of the language (or else are encoded as W-types, or with church encodings).  Things in the context don't have computation rules, generally.

Comment: "it was possible to distinguish extensionally equal functions on intensional features"  It's more like "it's not possible to show that you can't distinguish functions on intensional features".  Without classical logic, you can't eliminate the double-negation.